# Do BIOS viruses actually exist "in the wild" commonly?

Tags: bios, virus

My BIOS is acting up, resetting settings to default (even though battery is fine).
Probably something defective with the MotherBoard, but thought I'd check on this possibility.

Comment: It doesn't look like a virus. A virus would be much more annoying. Make sure the CMOS is at 3V, some motherboard have a reset button on it, Check your motherboard manual for it. It's best to hold it 10 seconds.

Comment: The behavior you describe is not likely to be a virus.  The purpose of a virus that infected the firmware of a piece of hardware, would to remain hidden, if the virus is detected you as the owner end removing it.

Comment: Yes they do, https://usa.kaspersky.com/internet-security-center/definitions/boot-sector-virus

Comment: Best way to avoid MBR infections is not to use MBR partitions and use GPT partitions.